# how can i set landscape orientation when playing a video from webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, orientation

i have a webview with a video link, the app is only portrait orientation but i need to change orientation when the video is in fullscreen and use all screen.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: try this https://gist.github.com/a4arpan/e53979d53e79d6e4b1c5ff82724fa70b

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put this in your `AppDelegate`:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    id presentedViewController = [window.rootViewController presentedViewController];
    NSString *className = presentedViewController ? NSStringFromClass([presentedViewController class]) : nil;

    if (window && [className isEqualToString:@"AVFullScreenViewController"]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Note: I have *not* tested this with iOS7 but works well with iOS8

Comment: The method signature is incorrect - should return UIInterfaceOrientationMask instead of NSUInteger. Technically, its the same, but I think Xcode will complain.

Comment: I don't get it @MichaelCueno This was an answer based on the documentation provided by Apple 3 Operating Systems ago. I can't say what you've stated is either correct or incorrect because I haven't looked at the documentation for over a year now as I'm on hiatus from work to travel. I'm sure Apple has deprecated numerous things. If you have a better answer for iOS ≥10 then please provide it as answer for others to see, usually comments don't catch people's eyes. Man getting this notification makes me miss it though :/

Comment: I think @Michael Cueno means,  in XCode 8, the IDE will complain the return value should be `UIInterfaceOrientationMask`, not `NSUInteger`

Comment: This is the best & simple solution ever for this issue! Great job!

Answer (score 4):

**In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28467104/3868736) for iOS 7 and iOS 8**

Put in AppDelegate. Work for iOS 7 and iOS 8:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

    id presentedViewController = [window.rootViewController presentedViewController];
    NSString *className = presentedViewController ? NSStringFromClass([presentedViewController class]) : nil;


    if (window && ([className isEqualToString:@"MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController"] || [className isEqualToString:@"AVFullScreenViewController"])) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }

}
```