# React Native: Allow device rotation only when webview plays video

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webview, react-native

My current working app is locked in portrait mode through entire screens.
The app plays embedded YouTube videos on webview and I just want to allow the landscape mode only when it plays in full screen.

I see there are some tricks for native ways and I think there aren't compatible with React Native. I also checked [react-native-orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation) but it doesn't help me.

Is there a simple and clean way I can implement this?

Comment: Hi oscar, I can recommend you a way but still not sure if its for you. Display your video thumbnail with a play icon above it. when user press it, open a Modal that contains your VideoPlayer, and in styles of that videoplayer make it rotate 90 degrees to the left or right. This won't change ever, so it won't be 100% user friendly. if `react-native-orientation` doesn't help you, you can only use some js tricks for now or write a native component yourself (Also if you use `react native video`, there is an option to make it fullscreen by calling a function.)

Comment: Hi Enie, react-native-video would be an alternative ways but I can't figure out how can play YouTube videos by react-native-video because I can't get direct reference to youtube file.

Comment: You can use `react-native-youtube` but don't use npm install. Im using this repo and its npm was old, better install directly from git. You can pass youtube id as prop to play YT videos

Comment: I just want a player which can play youtube & vimeo videos. If I use react-native-youtube, it can't play vimeo videos.

Comment: You can check the source of the provided link whether its a youtube url or video. Then render which player thats required simply in your render function.

Comment: AFAIK this is all you can do for now im afraid.

Comment: For the iOS version you can use the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465612/how-can-i-set-landscape-orientation-when-playing-a-video-from-webview

Answer (score 7):

I may be a little late to the party but I've recently added what your question is requesting.

**Our goal**

The application should be fixed to a portrait orientation, unless a User is watching a video. When watching a video, Users should be able to freely switch between portrait and landscape.

**Getting Started**

I'll outline how I did it in iOS, the React Native part certainly works on Android too.

**Enable ALL orientations**

You wan't to enable all orientations (Portrait, Upside Down, Landscape Left, Landscape Right).

I've taken the following image from Google, just ensure all checkboxes are ticked.

[image]

**React Native Package**

Download [`react-native-orientation`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation) and inside of your `index.ios.js`, add the code to lock the device orientation.

For example, mine's inside a `componentWillMount`.

```
componentWillMount() {
  Orientation.lockToPortrait();
}
```

**Disable lock when watching a Video via a WebView**

I then have a simple `VideoPlayer` component.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.handleClick}>
  <WebView
    source={{uri: 'https://youtube.com'}}
  />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

I used `TouchableWithoutFeedback` as I don't want the User to know that they've clicked something.

Create a `handleClick` function:

```
handleClick = () => {
  Orientation.unlockAllOrientations()
}
```

**The tricky bit, and it's hacky!**

I couldn't find a way to tell when the User had finished watching a Video within a WebView. This is because iOS uses its native player.

My `VideoPlayer` component is within a `ScrollView` (amongst other components). When the User scrolls (after watching a video), the application will again lock back to a portrait orientation.

```
<ScrollView
  onScroll={() => { Orientation.lockToPortrait(); }}
/>
```

**Note**

This will lock on all devices, including Tablets. If you want to only run it on a phone, I use [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) to detect whether the device is a tablet or not.

You could wrap all your orientations within an if statement:

```
if (!DeviceInfo.isTablet()) {
  Orientation.lockToPortrait();
}
```